# How Should i add camera plugin with image suggestions like below image in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I added `ionic` native camera plugin it's working fine.

But i want the camera plugin like whatsapp. because i want to show gallery image suggestion in camera plugin below section it self

[image]

Check above image fro reference.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no native plugin for your requirements and also what you are looking is custom things which you need to write above Native plugin.

But as many developer have this kind of requirements.

Please find below Github link for Customized camera.

Link : https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-plugin-instagram-assets-picker

**Sample Code to use plugin method for Gallery:**

```
InstagramAssetsPicker.getMedia(
  function(result) { // success cb
    console.log('getMedia success, result: ', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    // result will be an object with at least a phAssetId, filePath, and type property
    // you will only get the rect object when 'cropAfterSelect' is false
    // the rect object is required for the cropAsset function documented below

    /* example of result when the 'cropAfterSelect' option is set to false
    {
      phAssetId: "A1785F1A-EF0F-458C-9AF9-C439981CE0FB/L0/001",
      type: "video",
      rect: {
        Width: 0.5625000293366611,
        Height: 0.9999999823048711,
        Y: 0,
        X: 0.2496093880181434
      },
      filePath: "file:///Users/rossmartin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6465544C-C262-4EA8-BA7C-8BAB4AB98597/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.m4v"
    }
    */
  },
  function(err) { // error cb
    console.log('getMedia error, err: ', err);
  },
  { // options
    type: 'video', // accepts 'photo', 'video', or 'all' - defaults to all
    cropAfterSelect: false, // see the note above for when this is false - defaults to false
    showGrid: false // determines whether to show the grid for cropping - defaults to false
  }
);
```

You can use it directly or take fork edit as per your requirements.

Hope this will helps.